# Error accessing the entity model in a seperate project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two projects one of which contains the entity model and acts as the DAL and the other one consumes that model and implements the application logic.

The model is a class library project and the application is a windows forms projects.

Having the following app.config files of the projects, and having referenced System.Data.Entity in the forms project, when I run the WinForms app, I get the following error:

**Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application**

Where you think the problem might be?

DAL Project's app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProviderInterfaceContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProviderInterfaceModel.csdl|res://*/ProviderInterfaceModel.ssdl|res://*/ProviderInterfaceModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.2.12;initial catalog=ProviderInterface;user id=--;password=---;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="PrizeServiceSoap" name="PrizeServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The WinForms app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProviderInterfaceContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProviderInterfaceModel.csdl|res://*/ProviderInterfaceModel.ssdl|res://*/ProviderInterfaceModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.2.12;initial catalog=ProviderInterface;user id=---;password=----;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Added reference to EntityFramework 6.0 and EntityFramework.SqlServer and everything is working now.